# Language Injection - file pattern

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has option to automatically inject languages in certain places like Template Literal Strings, there are already some definitions in Settings, but they target code structure.

Is there any possibility to make it, so that file patterns are targeted?

For instance I would want to have files with pattern *.ts-templates.ts, to have TypeScript injected?

Any solution for this?

Comment: What is the problem of just having that file be typescript?

Comment: I have templates that match some language, and i just want to have all files that have some pattern that tell which language, to inject this automatically, instead of adding comment annotation